# Why backup and sync is often "stuck"

Tags: google-drive

It's often happen

[image]

Basically, it should update like 35 text files. However, it never finishes and just stuck.

The file is quite big 178 mb but it should not cause any problem. The internet is fast.

Quitting and restarting works. But I don't want that solution.

Comment: As you're asking about the backup and sync feature of Google Drive, rather than the web interface, your question is off-topic at web apps but should be on-topic at [su].

Comment: would someone move this to super user?